# What is the max number of hard links in OS X (10.11)?

Tags: macos, filesystem, hfs+

I have a file that I keep linking to.  It's up to 45 links now. Does anyone know how I can find out what the maximum number of hard links is in OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems the theoretical limit is [about 1 billion](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#HardLinks) hard links on an HFS+ volume.

> Indirect node files have a special identifying number called a link reference. The link reference is unique among indirect node files on a given volume. The link reference is not related to catalog node IDs. When a new indirect node file is created, it is assigned a new link reference randomly chosen from the range 100 to 1073741923.

The limit for links to a single file is [4294967295](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#HFSPlusPermissions), the maximum number of a UInt32, which is about four times larger than the volume limit, which you'll exhaust first.

> linkCount
>     For indirect node files, this field contains the number of hard links that point at this indirect node file.

As a *practical* matter, this design is quite strange, and suffers from performance issues. The more hard links you have on a volume, the slower it will be to create a new one, as the system must first find an unused link reference number, then insert it into the metadata directory. Then that metadata directory must be searched to dereference a hard link.

You may begin seeing performance problems with only a few thousand links; your great-grandchildren won't live long enough to create a billion if you start today. In practice you'll notice this most often when [managing Time Machine backups](http://www.cnet.com/news/progress-bar-hangs-when-emptying-trash-in-os-x/), which use hard links extensively.